# How to get a string from the FutureString

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-futurebuilder

I am new to flutter  i want to get string from other class and when i calls the function it returns either future string or null   But my console is printing the address ,
please any one can help me

iam trying to get address string but getting nothing

```
import 'package:geocoding/geocoding.dart';

class  LocationAndAddresses{

  String paddress = '';
  double? lat  ;
  double?  lng;

  void filllatlang(double lati,double long){

  }

  Future<void> convertCoordinatesToAddress(double latitude, double longitude) async {
    try {
      List<Placemark> placemarks = await placemarkFromCoordinates(latitude, longitude);
      if (placemarks != null && placemarks.isNotEmpty) {
        Placemark placemark = placemarks[0];
        String address = placemark.street ?? '';
        String city = placemark.locality ?? '';
        String state = placemark.administrativeArea ?? '';
        String country = placemark.country ?? '';
        String postalCode = placemark.postalCode ?? '';
        paddress='$address $city$state $country$postalCode';
        print('Address: $address, $city, $state, $country, $postalCode');

      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error: $e');
    }
  }

  Future<void> convertAddressToCoordinates(String address) async {
    try {
      List<Location> locations = await locationFromAddress(address);
      if (locations != null && locations.isNotEmpty) {
        Location location = locations[0];
        double latitude = location.latitude;
        double longitude = location.longitude;
        filllatlang(latitude, longitude);
        print('Latitude: $latitude, Longitude: $longitude');
        lat=latitude;
        lng=longitude;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error: $e');
    }
  }

}
```

and here is page where i made  the call to this class

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:location/location.dart';
import 'package:untitled5/locationandaddress/locationandaddresses.dart';

class SeconPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const SeconPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SeconPage> createState() => _SeconPageState();
}

class _SeconPageState extends State<SeconPage> {
  final mycontroller = TextEditingController();
  String address = 'Rajanpur';
  LatLng coordinates = LatLng(29.1044, 70.3301);
  String gotresult = '';
  String mylat = '';
  String mylong = '';
  String adres = '';
  Future<String> getaddress() async {
    gotresult = await LocationAndAddresses().paddress;
    return gotresult;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    adres = getaddress().toString();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Coordinates to Address etc'),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    adres = getaddress().toString();
                  });
                },
                child: Text(
                  'press for Address',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
                )),
            Container(
                width: 400,
                height: 300,
                child: FutureBuilder(
                  future: getaddress(),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    return Text(snapshot.data.toString());
                  },
                ))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You are already using [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html), you dont have to call the future on initState, just check some connection state and then use or assign the snapshot.data

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Future variable to avoid getting  unexpected api call. If you need Future data on top level, use FutureBuilder on body/Scaffold based on your need.

I will recommend to check the [doc example.](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html)

```dart
class _SeconPageState extends State<SeconPage> {
  final mycontroller = TextEditingController();
  String address = 'Rajanpur';
  LatLng coordinates = LatLng(29.1044, 70.3301);
  String gotresult = '';
  String mylat = '';
  String mylong = '';
  String adres = '';
  Future<String> getaddress() async {
    gotresult = await LocationAndAddresses().paddress;
    return gotresult;
  }

  late final Future<String> future = getaddress();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
                width: 400,
                height: 300,
                child: FutureBuilder(
                  future: future,
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      adres = snapshot.data.toString();
                      return Text(adres);
                    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                      return Text('${snapshot.error}');
                    }
                    return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                  },
                ))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks but this code shows only  a container and shows neither the data nor the error i want a value  in the string of my display page

Comment: can you try to print the `snapshot`, it might be returning empty data

Comment: Latitude: 29.104429900000003, Longitude: 70.330117329.104429900000003hoo70.3301173
I/flutter ( 5203): Address: Humza Colony Fazilpur, Fazilpur, Punjab, Pakistan,

Comment: i got above print statement in    class  LocationAndAddresses   however  in class where i made a call to display i got only null

Comment: does it happen from `adres = snapshot.data.toString(); return Text(adres)`